# Linking an image to a lightbox on jqZoom

Tags: jquery, jqzoom

I'd like to use jqZoom with an image-link like it's shown here: http://www.lumas.de/pictures/christophe_jacrot/gold/

So far I've only seen examples with just the jqZoom but no actual link on the image: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1. Is there a setting or option I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.lumas.de/pictures/christophe_jacrot/gold/
```

In this page they use something called `jQuery_tools_overlay.js`

That is what produces that overlay when the image is clicked.

Documentation of that is here: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html

And `jqZoom` has nothing to do with that.